# How to optimise MySQL insert that uses select where in clause

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I have several queries along the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO my_data_archive.my_table (id, FieldName, Value, Position, PageId) 
  SELECT id, FieldName, Value, Position, PageId FROM my_data.my_table 
  WHERE PageId IN 
    (SELECT id FROM my_data.page WHERE PageTypeId BETWEEN 33 AND 36 AND Deleted IS NULL)
```

I also have some queries like

```
INSERT INTO my_data_archive.my_table (id, FieldName, Value, Position, PageId) 
  SELECT id, FieldName, Value, Position, PageId from my_data.my_table 
  WHERE PageId IN (SELECT id FROM my_data.page WHERE CreatedTimestamp <= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),INTERVAL 3 YEAR) AND Deleted IS NULL)
```

Basically these are bulk inserts designed to archive off old data into a new schema. The query takes all the data (in my_table) that belongs to 'pages' (in the page table) of a certain type or older than 3 years and inserts it into the archive table.

The performance of the inserts is very slow due to the amount of data and probably a pretty suboptimal query. What would be the best way to improve the performance of this insert? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: Is the performance of the inserts significantly worse than performance of the selects by themselves? In general, MySQL is poor at optimizing `WHERE column IN (subquery)`, you should use `JOIN` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the construct `IN ( SELECT ... )`.  Change to a `JOIN`.  For example:

```
SELECT  t.id, t.FieldName, t.Value, t.Position, t.PageId
    FROM  my_data.my_table AS t
    JOIN  my_data.page AS p  ON p.id = t.PageId
    WHERE  p.PageTypeId BETWEEN 33 AND 36
      AND  p.Deleted IS NULL )
```

And add these composite indexes to `page`:

```
INDEX(Deleted, CreatedTimestamp)
INDEX(Deleted, PageTypeId)
```

The `INSERT` part of your query will take some time.  Hopefully the above suggestions will help enough.